# What must be done for a static template function defined in a nested class to be declared a friend in a sibling nested class?

Tags: c++, templates, friend, nested-class, template-function

Using GCC 4.8.2 on Linux, I want to grant the factory method Create() access to the private constructor of class C, but I get "error: 'Create' was not declared in this scope" when attempting to declare a specialized friend. How do I get this to work without opening up the declaration to all types for B::Create()?

```
template <typename T> class A {
 public:
  class B;
  template <typename U> class C;
};

template <typename T>
class A<T>::B {
 public:
  template <typename U> static void Create();
};

template <typename T> template <typename U>
class A<T>::C {
  C() = default;
  friend void B::Create<U>();
};

template <typename T> template <typename U>
void A<T>::B::Create() {
  C<U>{};
}

int main() {
  A<int>::B::Create<char>();
}
```

Comment: Aha! It works in clang++ if we befriend a specific specialization of `B::Create`, e.g. `friend void A<int>::B::Create<int>();` In g++4.9.2, this leads to an ICE o.O

Comment: Kaslai found that full qualification was needed for it to work in MSVC++.

Comment: Well, that is not sufficient to make it work with g++ nor clang++. However, if we try to use a fixed, known type instead of the template parameter `T` in the friend-declaration (i.e. instead of `friend void A<T>::B::Create<U>();` we write `friend void A<int>::B::Create<char>();`, it works for clang++, but g++ crashes (ICE).

Comment: `friend void A<int>::B::Create<char>();` makes g++5.0 tip-of-trunk crash with an ICE, so that's at least *one* bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have run into a compiler defect. The following code, that uses only one layer of templates, works fine in g++ 4.8.2.

```
class Foo
{
   public:
      template <typename U> static Foo* Create();
};

template <typename U> class Bar : public Foo
{
   private:
      Bar() = default;

      friend Foo* Foo::Create<U>();
};

template <typename U>
Foo* Foo::Create() {
  return new Bar<U>();
}
```

However, the same compiler fails to compile your code. One work around, which I think you have already tried, is to replace

```
friend B* B::Create<U>();
```

with

```
template <typename V> 
friend B* B::Create<V>();
```

Comment: Yes, as you suspected I am aware the workaround you propose does work. Unfortunately, as you know, it provides much broader access to Bar from Foo::Create (i.e. for all U).

Comment: In the OP's case, I think we have a dependent base class, this might change a conforming interpretation. Note that coliru.stacked-crooked.com's clang++ has a similar issue with the OP's code: It complains about a missing definition of `Create`, which might be the result of the friend-declaration introducing *another* `Create` function that is selected by overload resolution later. If that's the case, this could be a funny name lookup issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code in MSVC++ and it was failing there too. I was able to fix it by just giving the friend declaration a more explicit name. Remember, you can provide fully qualified names anywhere!

I just replaced

```
friend B* B::Create<U>();
```

with

```
friend B* A<T>::B::Create<U>();
```

I'll fire up MinGW and see if it actually does what you expect it to do.

Comment: With GCC 4.8.2, I see the same error with the more explicit name.

Comment: Okay, on my version of MinGW (GCC 4.7.1) I'm having the same issue as you, but the same code compiles just fine in MVC++. I'll see if I can figure out how to fix it, but it might be time to submit a bug report.

Comment: Eh, anything I tried (other than what R Sahu suggested) wouldn't work in either MinGW 4.7.1 or GCC 4.8.2 on Linux. Oh well.